# How to connect device with UDP protocol on local network?

Tags: ethernet, port-forwarding, lan, switch

I have simple data logger which send data (some id, date, time...) every second. This device was connected with windows app by Ethernet cable. Now I would like to connect device with my modem and access data using android app (UDP Client).
How to do connection? Do I need some additional hardware, for example LAN switch or something else? Do I need to set parameters in my modem for port forwarding or something else?

Comment: Please be more specific, such as what kind of datalogger and app(s) do you use? Is the Android device connected to the same network? What have you tried and what were the results?

Comment: Device is one grey closed box with one Ethernet cable. I don't know what kind of hardware is inside.  My job is to transfer information further to local network, and to create android tablet app to read that information from network, and display to end users. Something like UDP server/client communication. Until now I connected device to modem and use Fing app to confirme that device is visible on local network. Also I used WireShark windows app to find device ip address, port number and protocol (UDP). At the end I tried some UDP client app from android market to read data but unsucesfuly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. This answer is in case the someone have similar problem. 

You need to do next:

- connect device direct to yours computer with Ethernet cable
- used WireShark app to find ip address, port and protocol (utp
  protocol in     my case)
- after get device data,  disconect device and reconnect    directly with yours modem (no need for aditional device like ethernet switch, or to    do the port forwarding)
- you can use some udp    client app on android phone to check if data
  are receiving (I used    TCP Sender / Receiver). Just set ip address
  and    port.

My problem was  because I used wrong UDP client app. That's the reason it didn't working from the beginning.